# Can't see AJAX call in proxy/chrome's dev tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following code snippet is used by a coworker to get an URL from a DB and then submit a "virtual" form to that URL.

```
$.ajax({
                url: location.origin + location.pathname + "data/getURL.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    userName: user
                },
                success: function( data : any, textStatus : string, jqXHR : JQueryXHR){
                    console.log(data);
                    var url = (JSON.parse(data)).url;

                    if(url !== undefined && url !== null && url !== ""){
                        var sender : HTMLFormElement = document.createElement("form");
                        sender.setAttribute("action", `http://${url}/receive`);
                        sender.setAttribute("method", "POST");

                        var userSenderField = document.createElement("input");
                            userSenderField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                            userSenderField.setAttribute("name", "user");
                            userSenderField.setAttribute("value", user);
                        sender.appendChild(userSenderField);

                        var passSenderField = document.createElement("input");
                            passSenderField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                            passSenderField.setAttribute("name", "password");
                            passSenderField.setAttribute("value", password);
                        sender.appendChild(passSenderField);

                        document.body.appendChild(sender);
                        sender.submit();
```

Using either Burp Suite or just Chrome's Dev Tools, I can see the call to `getURL.php` but then I can't see the call to `http://url/receive`. Why?

Comment: on sender.submit() you should probably be redirected to that url

Comment: why is your coworker  doing this? security through obscurity?

Comment: @madalinivascu that's the point, I should be able to see that redirection, right? And btw, you shouldn't be so hurry to call someone dumb if you don't know the logic behind the infrastructure. The code is perfectly valid from a security point of view, and no, it's not security through obscurity.

Comment: i sad dumbest thing not dumbest person , you are just adding complexity to your code in my opinion from which you reach a case like this

Comment: @yzT does the call to `getURL` actually succeed? (can you see the log line from `console.log(data)`)?

Comment: @madalinivascu and I repeat, you don't know the logic behind (it's irrelevant for the question), so you don't know whether or not he's adding complexity (I'm already telling you he's doing the right thing in this snippet)

Comment: if the page redirects he wouldn't be able to see it

Comment: can you explain the logic in your script so we can properly help you

Comment: @madalinivascu isn't the success handler supposed to get called regardless of a redirect happening in between (as long as the call succeeds)?

Comment: @TimothyGroote is this javascript executed on the server side?

Comment: @TimothyGroote you lose the state once the page is reloaded

Comment: @madalinivascu your question makes no sense to me. it's obviously client side. besides, isn't the whole point of ajax *NOT* reloading the entire page?

Comment: @TimothyGroote you just helped me out finding what was the problem. I was testing with fake users, so the call to `getURL` never succeeded and therefore, the script didn't call the form. Using a real user, I can see the call :)

Comment: @yzT that once more illustrates the importance of adding an error handler to your ajax calls. :)

Comment: @TimothyGroote he is reloading the page when he triggers the submit on the "virtual" form

Comment: @madalinivascu ohh i get it now. that construction is kinda weird, yeah.

Comment: @TimothyGroote add an answer saying what was the problem, so I can accept it

Comment: Well technically, @madalinivascu was onto what happened before i was. the call actually succeeded, but since your code immediately added a new form to the page and submitted it, you never got to see what exactly was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of argument, let's say your ajax call to `data/getURL.php` succeeded, but delivered bad or unexpected data.

You then end up in your ajax call's success handler.

The success handler immediately creates a new form, populates it with (the bad) data, and submits the form.

This causes a postback to happen.

Chrome's dev tools clear the network panel upon postback by default, also clearing the call to `"data/getURL.php"`, so you never actually saw the call succeed, and could not see in the net panel what it did. (ergo, you had no idea that `data/getURL.php` delivered the wrong data to you.

if you put a breakpoint in your ajax success handler before it submits the form, you can actually see what is going on.

Comment: i might add that getting an url from an ajax call, then doing a postback with it seems like an odd, somewhat inelegant solution. i'm sure there are better, less error-prone ways of doing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: in my opinion he needs to get rid of the ajax call and do a redirect from getURL.php to the url that he gets from ajax

Comment: @madalinivascu that would save an unnecesary roundtrip, yes.